# Ajax success, complete, error function is not calling jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, nette

I have problem with jQuery Ajax calling method success. I tried everything but success is not calling. My code looks like

```
$('#target').submit(function(event) {
    // get the form data
    var formData = {
        'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'surname': $('input[surname=surname]').val(),
    };

    // process the form
    $.nette.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: {link Admin:uploadData}, 
        data: formData, // our data object
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        off: ['unique'],
        success: function(payload){
            console.log(payload.message.lol);
        }
    })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I am using nette web framework. When I debug code in Firefox I get a response like this:

[image]

Tkanks for the advice.

Comment: I believe `$('input[surname=surname]').val()` should be `$('input[name=surname]').val()`, also remove `async: false`. It's a really bad idea.

Comment: what is that off property?

Comment: I dont know, i just found it in nette.org forum. I use Ajax for the 1st time so I dont know what it is doing. But when I delete row off... it also not work.

Comment: don't just copy and paste everything you see on the internet without knowing what it does lol

Comment: Yeah I know but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: what does console.log(payload) display?

Comment: Nothing, it looks like it not calling console.log... I tried console.log('string') but it writes nothing to console too. So I think that success is not calling.

Comment: `off` [apparently](https://github.com/vojtech-dobes/nette.ajax.js#useful-tricks) signifies what plugins should be disabled during the call.

Comment: What version of nette.ajax.js do you use? Where did you get it?

Comment: I use `nette.ajax` from here [nette.ajax](https://addons.nette.org/vojtech-dobes/nette-ajax-js)

Answer (score 1):

You don’t even need nette.ajax for this, plain [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will suffice.

```
$('#target').submit(function(event) {
    // get the form data
    var formData = {
        'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
        'surname': $('input[name=surname]').val(),
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // assuming #target is a form, we can use its action
        data: formData, // our data object
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(payload) {
            console.log(payload.message.lol);
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Also, as *@Rory McCrossan* commented, `async` property will only make your site freeze, don’t use it unless you really know you need it.

Comment: Thanks with this url, but when I use jQuery.ajax, I get as answer whole HTML page without JSON data.

Comment: jQuery should add `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header, which you can detect using [`isAjax`](https://api.nette.org/2.4/Nette.Application.UI.Presenter.html#_isAjax) method in the presenter and send a JSON payload in that case.

Comment: yeah I know but its not working. I got as response always whole html page.